# Close db connection

Tags: php, destructor, unset

i've founded in the web a class that i needed. This class during her lifecycle open a connection with a local MySql db.

In my code the scope of this class instance is local, like this example

```
function doSomething(){
    $class = new MyClass();
    // ... do something with $class
}

doSomething();
```

So every time the function end the object is destroyed. But i think the db connection never stops right because after a certain number of call to doSomething class going into error 'cannot connect to database'.

Seeing the class' destructor the only operation it perform is

```
unset($this);
```

Does unset($this) close also db connection? What's the best way to close it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __destruct()
{
unset($objname);
session_destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP closes mysql connection at the end of request [Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php)

If you run doSomething several times during script execution - you can add mysql_close into destructor

Also, you can use persistent connections ([mysql_pconnect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)), which will give you better performance

Just to notice - its better to use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension

Comment: I use a third party class that in destructor only have one instruction:  unset($this);   So this mean that mysql link (i don't known how it is open, is inside the class) are not close right?

Comment: at least looks so, try to look throuht all files to find any "connect(" substring - usually it is place where connection is made

Answer (score 0):

**I just wrote the following, hope it helps:**

```
class db {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connection('localhost','user','pass','dbname');
    }

    public function mysql_q($sql) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$sql);
        return ($result) ? true : false;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        mysqli_close($this->conn);
    }
}

$db = new db(); // auto call __construct to connect db
echo ($db->mysql_q($sql)) ? "Successful!" : "Failed!";
unset($db); // auto call __destruct to close connection
```